# restricting image size and type in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input with type=file. This is used to upload images. Now I want to restrict images size to 500 kb and type to .png only. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible through javascript alone as it has no access to the local filesystem to check the file size before it is uploaded.

The workaround is to use Flash, which does have local file access, or to check the file on the server side, however this is not ideal as it still means that a large file can be uploaded before it is checked for file size validity.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can restrict sizes of file using javascript, for file extensions, you could do something like:

```
var ext = $('#my_file_field').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['png']) == -1) {
    alert('invalid extension!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would have to be done serverside. I don't believe you can detect the size of a file upload in jQuery. This is because JavaScript has no access to the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000" />
```

The value specified is the maximum allowable KB to be uploaded via this form. A value of 100000 will allow a file up to 100kb.

However, this is HTML and can be bypassed, you will still need to do PHP/Server Side validation like:

```
IF($_FILES['file']['size'] > 500000){// show error}
```

In php, the size value is in bytes

You can check the $_FILES['file']['type'] to restrict it to png files only, eg:

```
IF($_FILES['file']['type'] != "image/jpeg"){// show error}
```

Comment: MAX_FILE_SIZE is in bytes, not Kb. Also, it's support is very patchy at best, and it throws no trappable errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
var size = thefile.size;

var ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase(); 
if(ext=="png" && size=500000)
return true;
else
alert("invalid filetype or size greater than 500kb");
```